# send user to a specific part of the page without using link element

Tags: html

I know that it is possible to send a user to a specific a name by using a link; however, for what I'm doing, I'd prefer not to use this link element.

```
Ex:
http://www.domain.com/link.php#aname

will send the user down to

<a name="aname">
```

Is there a method of doing this on page load, like perhaps adding a line of code to the body tag or something?

I'm using this in conjunction with PHP, so basically if a particular variable is defined, I will be sending them to the location.  I know how to do the PHP side of it, just not the html side of it without the use of the link element.

Comment: not in html, you will need javascript.

Comment: any idea of what I need to search for to find what I am trying to do?  I don't even know really what the accurate terminology for this is.

Comment: "javascript scrollto()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the animate method from jquery to get a nice smoothe effect

```
$("#down").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#b").offset().top
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGk5F/)

---

Update: onload

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#b").offset().top
    });
});
```

Cheers!!

Comment: how can i apply this to an onload?

Comment: @kdjernigan - check answer above

Answer (score 1):

Few Assumptions :

- You know/declared the ID/NAME
- You are sure that a NAME/ID exist

Recommendation :

- Use Id along with the name.
- Make sure you have unique Id for that part of page where you want to send the user to.

Add this simple javascript before the end of `</body>` tag OR after all ids are `echo`

`<script type="text/javascript">window.location.hash=id;</script>`

Please change `id` to your required id. Once the page load first the div with a declared id is created and when everything is complete the javascript will try to move the page to the specific part.

If you will use scrollto then it requires far more steps and is complicated. You will need to

- measure the page height
- measure the location of that id
- scroll to that id if possible

Hope it works for you